# Php - Checkbox does not work

Tags: php

i try to make checkboxes. When i click checkbox it makes isPremium = 1 if i click a checked checkbox it makes isPremium = 0

**However: when i click a checked checkbox it does not work..**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<?php
require 'connectDB.php';
$mysql = new mysql();
$mysql->connect();

$dbResult = mysql_query("select * from profiles");






echo "<form action='#' method='post'>";

$dbResult = mysql_query("select * from profiles");


while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($dbResult)) {

    if ($info['isPremium'] == 0)
        echo "<input type=checkbox name='check2[]' id='check2' value=" . $info['id'] . ">";
    else
        echo "<input type=checkbox name='check1[]' id='check1' value=" . $info['id'] . " checked>";

    echo $info['profileName'] . "<br />";
}

echo "<p><input type='submit' name='btnPremium' /></p>";
echo "</form>";

if (isset($_POST['btnPremium'])) {


    if (isset($_POST['check2'])) {
        $arrPremium = $_POST['check2'];
        foreach ($arrPremium as $result) {
            mysql_query("UPDATE profiles set isPremium=1 where id=" . $result . "");
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        $arrPremium = $_POST['check1'];
        foreach ($arrPremium as $result2) {
            mysql_query("UPDATE profiles set isPremium=0 where id=" . $result2 . "");
        }
    }



}
?>
```

**when i click a checked checkbox it makes another checkbox unclick.**

This is the checkbox page

[image]

Comment: *when i click a checked checkbox it makes another checkbox unclick.*: What does this mean? It seems you only have one checkbox.

Comment: are you missing some **javascript** code maybe? This should just output a simple checkbox, I'm assuming you have other code that does an 'onclick' event of some kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to achieve, your code is needlessly complicated. You should use `isset` to check whether the value of a checkbox was included in the `$_POST` array. If yes, the checkbox was checked.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<?php
require 'connectDB.php';
$mysql = new mysql();
$mysql->connect();

echo "<form action='#' method='post'>";

$dbResult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profiles");
$profileid = array();

while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($dbResult)) {
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"" . $info['id'] . "\" " . ($info['isPremium'] != 0 ? "checked " : "") . "/>";
    echo $info['profileName'] . "<br />";
    $profileid[] = $info['id'];
}

echo "<p><input type='submit' name='btnPremium' /></p>";
echo "</form>";

if (isset($_POST['btnPremium'])) {
    foreach ($profileid as $id) {
        if (isset($_POST[$id])) {
            mysql_query("UPDATE profiles SET isPremium=1 WHERE id=" . $id);
        } else {
            mysql_query("UPDATE profiles SET isPremium=0 WHERE id=" . $id);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have refactored your code into this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<?php
require 'connectDB.php';
$mysql = new mysql();
$mysql->connect();

$update = (isset($_POST['check']) && is_array($_POST['check']));

$dbResult = mysql_query("select * from profiles");

echo "<form action='#' method='post'>";

while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($dbResult))
{
    if ($update)
    {
        $info['isPremium'] = (in_array($info['id'], $_POST['check']) ? 1 : 0);
        mysql_query("UPDATE profiles SET isPremium = " . $info['isPremium'] . " WHERE id = " . $info['id']);
    }

    echo "<input type=checkbox name='check[]' value=" . $info['id'] . ($info['isPremium'] == 0 ? "" : "checked") . " />";
    echo htmlspecialchars($info['profileName']) . "<br />";
}

echo "<p><input type='submit' name='btnPremium' /></p>";
echo "</form>";

?>
```

There were several problems with your original code:

1. Several HTML `input` elements with the same ID. This is wrong. We can have several elements with the same `name` attribute, but the `id` attribute should be unique for each element.
2. The database `UPDATE` code runs **after** displaying the form. This is wrong. In this case, we should update the database **prior** to generating the HTML output.
3. IMPORTANT: There is no need of two different `POST` arrays (check1 and check2). We only need **one array**. The **checked** boxes will be posted by the browser. The **unchecked** boxes will **not be posted** by the browser. As the **id** is the value, we can use the `in_array` function to verify if the checkbox for an item was checked or not.
4. It is a good idea to **escape** things you will output as HTML from the database. Otherwise, the application is vulnerable for some kinds of attack. The function `htmlspecialchars` is useful for this purpose.

Answer (score -1):

Checkboxes typically send the value `"on"` to the server, regardless of what `value` attribute is set. If you can, try to use radio buttons instead, as these send the proper `value` to the server. If that's not an option, have the name of the checkbox be `check1[".$info['id']."` and access `array_keys($_POST['check1'])`.